# Как передавать конфигурацию приложению?

Tags: веб-программирование

Любое приложение при запуске требует конфигурационный файл в котором буду указаны такие параметры для приложения как: максимальный размер файла, на каком порту слушать трафик, что писать в теле ответа на путь /helloWorld, и прочее. Такие входные параметры обычно небольшие да и это не трудно (хоть и если честно напрягает) указать их, но что если приложение можно очень сильно конфигурировать и параметров может быть очень много, и некоторые из них очень длинные (типа json схема). Некоторые из параметров можно изменить в runtime. Я подумал что это можно решить двумя способами:

1. Хранить все это в базе данных, нормализовать. Дать доступ к бд и пусть приложение само читает конфиги и все хорошо, в качестве входного параметра приложению нужно будет указать просто доступ к бд. Мне кажется что это самый очевидный способ но в нем есть не только плюсы

Какие я вижу минусы :(

- самое главное: без этой бд не будет работать приложение, нужно будет всегда таскать эти доступы к бд. Что если приложение охота отдать в open source, придется писать людям что нужно поднять такую то бд, туда поставить такие таблицы и пр.. ну это бред..
- нужно создавать бд, ее нужно будет бекапить, смотреть за ней чтобы ничего не упало, править схему таблиц
- как известно в бд нету версионирования, а некоторые параметры могут быть сложными и я хотел бы иметь какой нибудь code review прежде чем этот параметр установился и все инстансы приложения установили его себе. все таки мгновенное обновление записей тоже не всегда прям так необходимо. таким образом можно "запороть" все инстансы

  - какую бд выбрать для этого? документную типа mongo или orientdb? или реляционную? Ааа, так много выбора..
  - сделать select к бд сложнее чем прочесть файл

Плюсы :)
 - одна бд шарит параметры для кучи инстансов приложений, единое хранилище

2. Храним все в файлах, пусть приложение читать все из файловой системы.

какие минусы я вижу :(
 - нужно как то создавать кучу файлов на сервере где крутится приложение
 - я не хочу лазить на сервер каждый раз когда нужно будет добавить или поменять какой то параметр
 - файловая система медленная и постоянно читать оттуда не стоит, нужно будет обязательно применять кеширование

какие плюсы :)

- приложение работает в standalone. ему не нужно постоянное подключение к какой нибудь базе
- можно создавать какие угодно конфиги: xml, json, yaml.

Как можно убрать минусы? 
Я подумал что так как параметры могут быть сложными, и им нужно версионирование то единственный вариант это использовать VCS, я уверенно владею git. 
Там вести code review, делать мержи, и прочее. 
Приложению нужно будет только указать репозиторий с конфигами.
Я пишу на scala и мои приложения крутятся на jvm, я нашел библиотеку jgit, подумал что можно ее использовать чтобы работать с репозиторием.
Получается что конфиг файлы это не просто файлы а файлы под git. Можно будет делать переодические pull с удаленного репозитория таким образом управляя приложением(ями) просто сделав коммит в репозитории с конфигами.

У меня есть опыт программирование фронтэенда, пользуюсь npm, typescript. так вот, по сути npm ведь тоже так же работает. он просто скачивает js зависимости которые мы потом встраиваем в свои приложения. можно же чуть поменять код прям в node_modules но никто так не делает конечно =) Эти сторонние библиотеки хранятся в git и копируются npm'ом к нам.
Или например typescript использует dts файлы в которых описаны интерфейсы на typescript к различным библиотекам js. Эти DTS так же хранятся в обычном git репозитории и от туда копируются к нам в файловую систему.

как быть? стоит ли заморачиваться с jgit или все слишком перемудрил?  :)

Comment: В БД тоже можно хранить файлы. А в некоторых даже есть специальные типы данных для xml и json. А уж сколько версий туда можно понапихать...

Comment: Минусы БД надуманны. Приложение может само создать нужные таблицы, заполнить значения по умолчанию, следить за версиями, и для этого даже есть куча готовых инструментов - погуглите "миграции бд". Бэкапить надо будет не только бд, но и файлы конфигов тоже при их наличии. Вместо "большой" БД можно взять sqlite3, которая вполне standalone - так, например, делают все Android-приложения.

Comment: Mikhail Vaysman, проблема не с паролями связана а с большими параметрами, но спасибо, не знал про такие проекты как consul.

Comment: Sergey, знаю, может я действительно надумал минусы насчет бд но все равно придется таскать доступ к этой бд и приложение будет завязано на ней.  Я знаю что в бд можно хранить много что, в постгресе хорошая поддержка json или можно использовать документную базу

Comment: andreymal, я тоже думал насчет встраиваемой бд, но с ней будут возникать такие же вопросы как и с внешней бд. все равно прийдется бекапить как то, где то хранить.

Comment: @andreymal у БД есть главный минус - настройки подключения к БД тоже нужно где-то хранить

Comment: @MikhailVaysman что общего вы нашли у настроек приложения и системных паролей?

Comment: @AlexanderKondaurov любой конфиг тоже всё равно придётся бекапить как-то, где-то хранить, никакой разницы

Comment: @andreymal, ну так да, нужно хранить любой конфиг, поэтому меня посетила мысль хранить это в git репозитории, таким образом это и бекап и можно шарить, не? Даже вот допустим если использовать consul, все равно настройки просто так не выдаются, там есть авторизация, а где хранить тогда эти доступы? У меня почему то вся эта история ассоциируется с курицей и яйцом =)

Comment: @AlexanderKondaurov конфиг привязан к конкретной системе, пользователи приложения должны создавать его самостоятельно и он не должен находиться в репозитории

Comment: @andreymal, вы правы конечно но все равно охота хранить данные в git и не бояться за них =) Я вроде нашел что хотел, это blackBox, https://www.man42.net/blog/2016/12/git-blackbox/

Comment: Ну как хотите, но по-хорошему так не делают

Answer (score 0):

> Как передавать конфигурацию приложению?

Если приложение должно использовать какой либо конфиг, то оно должно знать где взять или как получить конфигурационную информацию. Вариантов много:
* Захардкодить (для полноты картины)
* JVM параметры
* Конфиг файлы 
* БД (но путь к базе должен быть прописан в приложении)
* JNDI
* URL c которого приложение может получить данные

Ну можно много еще чего придумать. Каждый метод хорош по своему.

Теперь по существу. Я думаю надо жить проще. Начните с файликов. Файловая система конечно не быстрая, но и файлы у вас не большие. Если совсем медленно получается то надо добавить кеширование, потом, можно читать файл не каждый раз а скажем, раз в секунду/минуту/час. 
Если планируется множесто запущеных копий, тогда нужно думать о неком сервисе через который можно менять конфиги для запущеных приложений, что то типа координатора.